# Buckingham's Pi Theorem: Why does $G(\pi)=0$ imply $\pi$ must be a constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, bernoulli-equation

I'm learning [Buckingham's Pi Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem) and there are some conclusions that I just can't wrap my head around.

**What I Understand**

Given a unit-free equation F($v_1$, ..., $v_n$)=0 where vi are physical quantities (e.g. mass, velocity), then exists an equivalent G($\pi_i$, ..., $\pi_m$)=0 where $\pi_i$ are dimensionless quantities and *m* is potentially much smaller than *n*.

For instance, if

- $v_1$ = $v$: velocity of a fluid
- $v_2$ = $g$: gravity
- $v_3$ = $h$: height of a tank of said fluid

Then instead of finding an F($v$, $g$, $h$)=0, we might try to use Pi's theorem to find out how many and which dimensionless groups exist for this problem. After doing the whole dimensional matrix thing, we arrive at: $\pi_a$ = $\dfrac{gh}{v^2}$. And, actually, any $\pi^n$ is still in the same group, so $\pi_b$ = $\pi_a^{0.5}$ = $\dfrac{\sqrt{gh}}{v}$ can also be used as the $\pi$ quantity in this problem.

So, instead of finding F($v$, $g$, $h$)=0, we only need to worry about G($\pi$)=0, which should be much easier. Hooray!

**What I don't Understand**

My textbook says that

> [...] G($pi$)=0 implies $pi$ must be constant. So we set $pi$=k and we get $v=k\sqrt{gh}$, which is the Bernoulli formula for k=$\sqrt{2}$ [...]

Why does G($\pi$)=0 imply $\pi$ must be constant? Why can't G($\pi$) = $0 \times \pi = 0$, which would not constrain $\pi$ in any way?

Sometimes it says  that $G(\pi_1, \pi_2)=0$ imply we can do $\pi_1$ = f($\pi_2$). But why? If $G(\pi_1, \pi_2)= \pi_1 \times \pi_2=0$, then I don't think this implies there must exist a function that takes $\pi_1$ to $\pi_2$. It only means at least one of them must be 0. In a 2-D plane, it would be the union of the x-axis (y=0) and the y-axis (x=0), which is definitely not a function.

Am I missing something? To me it looks like a there's no formal logic leading up to these conclusions.

Comment: Should it say "given an equation with units, $F(v_i) = 0$, there exists an equivalent unit-less equation, $G(\pi_i) = 0$?" instead?

Comment: What does "unit-free" mean?

Comment: "unit-free" means that the 0 carries no unit. For instance, if F is the ratio between two masses, then this ratio is unit free, because whatever unit we choose to represent the mass, their ratio should be the same

Comment: That's a non-standard definition which I find confusing - it could be standard somewhere

Comment: What precise formulation of the theorem are you using? If you are not careful with the conditions on regularity of the functions, then yes, those kinds of pathological behaviour could sneak in, but a good source should provide suitably strong conditions on $F$ and sufficiently strong tooling to ensure that the $G$s you've written are ruled out. The details will depend on the version, so you should be clear on what statement and what proof you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only answers your second question,

> Sometimes it says that G(π1,π2)=0 imply we can do π1 = f(π2). But why?...

Your confusion here might stem from the notation that uses o (and sometimes $0$) to represent dimensionless values.
A *dimensionless* $\pi$ group multiplied by a $\pi$ group *with* dimensions does not output a dimensionless group.

Hence, for your second question, you can't reach the conclusion that only one of them is o. Also, each $\pi$ is already dimensionless as stated by the theorem's procedure.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, but I didn't understand your points.

In my example, G(π1,π2) = $0$ and π1 and π2 are dimensionless. G() is a dimensionless (or unit-free) equation, so $0$ carries no dimension either.

It would be something like G(Reynolds Number, Drag Coefficient) = $0$ $\implies$ Drag Coefficient = f(Reynolds Number). I don't understand where this conclusion comes from, mathematically speaking.

Comment: @William you said one of the pis being o would result in their product being o. This is obviously not correct - 1 times a velocity gives you velocity, not 1. Furthermore, each of the pis should be dimensionless already. Another possibility is that you're using o to represent the value zero, in which case you're not really talking about units anymore.

Comment: @William Perhaps you're thinking 0 is the value zero. But I believe your textbook uses 0 to mean dimensionless.